# if something Alert Dialog on button click issue android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(bob1i + bih1i > 4 || bob2i + bih2i > 4){
            error = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            error.setMessage("No more than four bags per team are allowed./n"
                +"Please review your scores.");

            error.setNeutralButton("Ok",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Review",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              });
              error.show(); 
            }
        }
   }
```

i then have an else statement for what happens if there is no error

i get the error at line 4 "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined" in eclipse

Comment: please be careful of formatting, keeping lines short prevents horizontal scrollbars which makes reading the code easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

The line with: `error = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

is passing a `View.OnClickListener` when it should be passing a `Context`.

You can't pass `this` as a `Context` when you're inside an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

As Scienceprodigy said, the error is that "this" is undefined within an anonymous class. But you can still make this work. Let's say you're trying to do this in some Activity with the class name MyActivity. Just do this:

```
error = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an `onClickListener()` instead of a `Context` because of the use of anonymous declaration.  Change it to this:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(bob1i + bih1i > 4 || bob2i + bih2i > 4){
            error = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            error.setMessage("No more than four bags per team are allowed./nPlease review your scores.");

            error.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Review", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            error.show();   
        }
    }
}
```